# adb>shell returns "error: closed" - how to "open" adb shell access through adb sideload

Tags: adb, shell, side-loading

my device got broken but i am still able to connect usb in the stock recovery mode.

if i try to start a shell via adb while the device is in recovery mode, i fail. my terminal echos the line: "error: "Closed".

i think, because this device isnt rooted/cfw, the official firmware blocks the shell access in recovery. but there must be a way to connect.

**what could i do to open a shell on this device?**

just reinstalling another OS through sideload isnt a option, the only way to access data is through adb

-there is a option in the recovery: "update via adb/sideload". when i choose this mode i can execute via adb a sideload update. the device recognizes the file and executes it.
- if try this with the same setup but another rooted device, i success.

Comment: The behavior is status-by-design. Your stock recovery is not designed to grant shell access. Your only choice here is to somehow manage to flash a custom recovery.

Comment: To achieve something similar to what @Firelord suggested: TWRP can be booted on many devices without being installed. For that, find a matching image, then boot to the bootloader and run `fastboot boot twrp.img`. Btw: you can check with `fastboot devices` resp. `adb devices` whether a device is visible to the corresponding tool.